# Add option and select that option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to append options to a select after receiving data from database.
And I cant select dynamically that option using jquery.
Any suggest?

add option:

```
$('#localidade').append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",14)
                .text(obj["NAME"]));
```

Select option:

```
$("#localidade").val(14);
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? What is the error that you got?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$('#localidade').append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",14)
            .text(obj["NAME"]));
```

To this line:

```
$('#localidade').append($('<option value="14">'+obj["NAME"]+'</option>');
```

If you inspect the HTML with the previous code, you will see that you were adding properties to #localidade